# Sumar valores de input con resultado de jQuery en un input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Mi problema es que ya obtuve los valores de una resta y los valores de una suma. Ahora lo que quiero es restar esos resultados pero no he podido hacerlo.

Dejo mi código por si alguien puede colaborarme.

Código:

```js
function resta() {
  var res = 0;
  var contador = 0;
  $('.cl').each(function() {
    if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
      res -= Number($(this).val());
      if (res < 0) {
        res = res * -1;
      }
      valor = "$ " + res;
      return contador = 1;
    }
  });
  $('#restall').val(valor);
};

function suma() {
  var add = 0;
  //contador = 1;
  $('.cla').each(function() {
    if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
      add += Number($(this).val());
      if (add < 0) {
        add = add * -1;
      }

      valor1 = "$ " + add;
    }
  });
  $('#sumaall').val(valor1);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-1wig" colspan="4">valor resta1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text2" class="cl form-control" type="text" name="TIOEP" onChange="resta();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor resta2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text2" class="cl form-control" type="text" name="MIFM" onChange="resta();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <!-- aca resto el valor1 y el valor 2-->
    <td class="tg-1wig" colspan="4">TOTAL resta
      <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
        <input id="restall" class="form-control" onChange="restadetodo();" type="text" name="restatodo" value="" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text3" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIDRD" onChange="suma();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text4" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIPE" onChange="suma();" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma3</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text5" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIPAENSAO" onChange="suma();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma4</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text6" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIOAEEMPA" onChange="suma();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">TOTAL suma</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="sumaall" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>




<table>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-1wig" colspan="4">valor resta1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text2" class="cl form-control" type="text" name="TIOEP" onChange="resta();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor resta2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text2" class="cl form-control" type="text" name="MIFM" onChange="resta();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <!-- aca resto el valor1 y el valor 2-->
    <td class="tg-1wig" colspan="4">TOTAL resta
      <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
        <input id="restall" class="form-control" onChange="restadetodo();" type="text" name="restatodo" value="" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text3" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIDRD" onChange="suma();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text4" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIPE" onChange="suma();" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma3</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text5" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIPAENSAO" onChange="suma();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma4</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text6" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIOAEEMPA" onChange="suma();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">TOTAL suma</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="sumaall" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Utilicé código que encontré en este mismo sitio y me funcionó, pero la verdad no he logrado hacer la resta de los valores finales.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien, tienes abajo otra tabla, quieres que ahí también se sume o reste independiente de la de arriba?

Comment: quisiera hacerlo si es posible que en el ultimo campo se resten los valores, es decir el valor de la resta menos el valor de la suma

Answer (score 0):

La función `restadetodo` no existía, así que la quito... Para que la función pueda ubicar en qué tabla se está escribiendo los números, primero hay que agregar el parámetro `this` en el `onchange`... También se puede agregar un `onkeyup`.

```html
onchange="resta(this);" onkeyup="resta(this);"
```

El parámetro `this` es el elemento actual. Por ejemplo:

```html
<input
    id="Text2"
    class="cl form-control"
    type="text"
    name="TIOEP"
    onchange="resta(this);"
    onkeyup="resta(this);"
/>
```

En este caso, el `this`, es el elemento que corresponde a la etiqueta `input` en que se está escribiendo el número. Este parámetro es para buscar la tabla padre más cercana, es decir, la etiqueta `table`.

En jQuery, para buscar la tabla padre más cercana, se hace mediante el método `closest`:

```html
var tabla = $(x).closest("table")
```

Una vez encontrada la tabla padre, se buscan todos los `input` de dicha tabla, es decir, las entradas.

```js
var entradas = tabla.find("input")
```

En la resta, se busca el primer y segundo `input` y se le resta el segundo al primero. El primero se hace mediante `.get(0)` y el segundo mediante `.get(1)`:

```js
var valor = (
    $(entradas.get(0)).val()
    -$(entradas.get(1)).val()
)
```

En la suma, partimos el array de entradas, desde la posición 3, hasta la 7 (no inclusive)... Vemos que 7 restado 3 es 4, que es la cantidad de entradas. Se va sumando al total el valor de cada entrada, mediante el método `each`.

```js
var valor = 0
entradas.slice(3,7).each( (a,b)=>{
  valor += +$(b).val()
})
```

Como se ve en el código anterior, la función que se le pasa al `each` tiene dos parámetros, en este caso los nombramos `a` y `b`... Nos interesa más el `b`, para obtener el valor de la entrada, aunque también se puede con `a`, que es el índice.

Para formatearlo a pesos, puede hacerse de varias maneras, preferentemente el signo pesos a la derecha del signo de resta:

```js
("$"+valor).replace("$-","-$")
```

Si se quiere el signo de resta a la derecha del signo pesos, no hay que hacer el `replace`.

Código completo:

```js
function resta(x) {
  var tabla = $(x).closest("table")
  var entradas = tabla.find("input")

  var valor = (
      $(entradas.get(0)).val()
      -$(entradas.get(1)).val()
  )

  tabla.find('#restall').val(
    ("$"+valor).replace("$-","-$")
  )
};

function suma(x) {
  var tabla = $(x).closest("table")
  var entradas = tabla.find("input")
  
  var valor = 0
  entradas.slice(3,7).each( (a,b)=>{
    valor += +$(b).val()
  })

  tabla.find('#sumaall').val(
    ("$"+valor).replace("$-","-$")
  )
};
```

```css
#sumaall, #restall{
  background: #80808070
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-1wig" colspan="4">valor resta1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text2" class="cl form-control" type="text" name="TIOEP" onchange="resta(this);" onkeyup="resta(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor resta2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text2" class="cl form-control" type="text" name="MIFM" onchange="resta(this);" onkeyup="resta(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <!-- aca resto el valor1 y el valor 2-->
    <td class="tg-1wig" colspan="4">TOTAL resta
      <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
        <input id="restall" class="form-control" type="text" name="restatodo" value="" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text3" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIDRD" onchange="suma(this);" onkeyup="suma(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text4" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIPE" onchange="suma(this);" onkeyup="suma(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma3</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text5" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIPAENSAO" onchange="suma(this);" onkeyup="suma(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma4</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text6" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIOAEEMPA" onchange="suma(this);" onkeyup="suma(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">TOTAL suma</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="sumaall" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<table border="2" >
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-1wig" colspan="4">valor resta1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text2" class="cl form-control" type="text" name="TIOEP" onchange="resta(this);" onkeyup="resta(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor resta2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text2" class="cl form-control" type="text" name="MIFM" onchange="resta(this);" onkeyup="resta(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <!-- aca resto el valor1 y el valor 2-->
    <td class="tg-1wig" colspan="4">TOTAL resta
      <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
        <input id="restall" class="form-control" type="text" name="restatodo" value="" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text3" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIDRD" onchange="suma(this);" onkeyup="suma(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text4" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIPE" onchange="suma(this);" onkeyup="suma(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma3</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text5" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIPAENSAO" onchange="suma(this);" onkeyup="suma(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">valor suma4</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="Text6" class="cla form-control" type="text" name="MIOAEEMPA" onchange="suma(this);" onkeyup="suma(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">TOTAL suma</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">
      <input id="sumaall" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```